# Azure function not showing up in portal

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-functions

I've written my first Azure Function and I've published it to azure. It said that the publish was successful and it created a new function app, but it's an empty one. I've done a bit of research into why my function wouldn't show up and I've seen that you might need to change the path to the zip deploy but I can't find where I need to change this and into what. Other solutions are always welcome! (I've published it directly from VS2017)

When I send a Postman Request to the `url/api/function`, it also doesn't work. It doesn't crash or anything, it just gives back nothing after a second.

I need this to work to create a custom connector for Power Automate that way I can use it in my Microsoft Flow.

Comment: Yes you cannot see when you have published from visual studio directly. But  you can see it if you browse `Resource Explorer`

Comment: Also can check using  this API `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subcriptionId/resourceGroups/ResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/YourFunctionAppName/diagnostics?api-version=2018-02-01`

Comment: Check your `Subscription`, `Resource Group name`, `Hosting Plan` while publish from Visual studio 2017

Comment: You can try and zip deploy your function app to see if it really is the build-/release pipeline that is failing. Navigate to <functionappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net, under Tools open Zip Push Deploy. You can zip the release or bin folder from your function app's project folder, and just drag-n-drop it into the zip push deploy. If it shows up in azure portal after doing this, you know it's the build-/release pipeline that is failing.

Comment: Have you really publish success? go to the kudu and have a look.

Comment: What the version of azure function you are using in your local unction app?

Comment: Can you try to deploy your code in new function instance on Azure?

Comment: OP usually answers his own question by himself that's why he didn't replied as his question is not fully clear as well.

Comment: I somewhat solved it by following the steps of creating a function in VS Code instead and publish that. It worked but now it gives an internal server error and debugging it doesn't work either because it just crashes when I want to run the function (before I can test the function, the function itself might not crash, I don't know that yet)